# I keep track of what's prior

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can mean to acquire;
>   For whomever's the buyer;
>   I can go down to the wire;
>   Though I often draw ire;
>   And when told by the choir;
>   My body's surely required.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may be

> **score**

I can mean to acquire; For whomever's the buyer;

> score - for a buyer to obtain, say illegal drugs

I can go down to the wire;

> the final score of a sporting match going down to the last second

Though I often draw ire;

> score - scratch or cut something

And when told by the choir; My body's surely required.

> score - written sheet music showing all parts is needed; possibly core as body

Title: I keep track of what's prior

> to keep the score - an account of past events, from a notch made as a tally mark

Answer (score 10):

I think you might be

> Hook

I can mean to acquire;

> To hook means to acquire or seize something (usually by means of a hook).

For whomever's the buyer;

> A hook can be a selling point or marketing scheme

I can go down to the wire;

> A hook can be found on the end of a fishing line

Though I often draw ire;

> Hook is the antagonist for Peter Pan

And when told by the choir;

> A hook is a device especially in music or writing that catches the attention.

My body's surely required.

> To hook means to work as a prostitute.

Title

> I think this refers to [Hooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking) in computer programming.

Comment: I was thinking of something else, but this is a great answer